# why angular is making 2 http post req

Tags: angularjs

```
li
      a.accordion-trigger(href='#accordion4', data-accord-group='group1')
        p(style='color:white;') 2. Subjects Average Pass Percentage :
      #accordion4.accordion-content.collapsed(ng-controller='ListController2', scroll='')
        form(ng-submit='addNew()')
          table.table.data.table-bordered
            thead
              tr
                th Subject Name
                th Year-Sem-Branch-Sec
                th No.of.Students Appeared (A)
                th Passed (B)
                th Pass Percentage (B/A*100)
                th
                  input.btn.btn-primary.add.pull-right(type='submit', value='Add New')
            tbody
              tr(ng-repeat='subjectAverage in subjectAverages')
                td.data
                  input(type='text', ng-model='subjectAverage.subjectName', required='')
                td.data
                  input(type='text', ng-model='subjectAverage.yearSem', required='')
                td.data
                  input(type='text', ng-keyup='calculatePercentage(subjectAverage)', ng-model='subjectAverage.studentsAppeared', required='')
                td.data
                  input(type='text', ng-keyup='calculatePercentage(subjectAverage)', ng-model='subjectAverage.studentsPassed', required='')
                td.data
                  input(type='text', ng-model='subjectAverage.percentage', disabled='disabled')
                td
                  input.btn.btn-danger.pull-right.delete(type='button', ng-click='removeRow($index)', value='Remove')
          table
            tr
              td Average : 
              td
                input(type='text', ng-model='subjectAverages[0].average')
        h3 Faculty text box (optional):
        .form-group
          textarea#comment.form-control(rows='3', ng-model='subjectAverages[0].facultyComment')
          button.btn.btn-default(type='submit', ng-click='saveavg()') Save
```

this is .pug code

angular controller code

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

    app.controller("ListController2", ['$scope','getAverage', '$rootScope','postSubAverage',function($scope,getAverage,$rootScope,postSubAverage)  {
  $scope.subjectAverages = [{
    'subjectName': '',
    'yearSem': '',
    'studentsAppeared': '',
     'studentsPassed':'',
     'percentage':'',
     'average':'',
     'facultyComment':'',
     'point':''
  }];

 $scope.calculatePercentage = function(val) {
    val.percentage = (parseFloat(val.studentsPassed)*100)/parseFloat(val.studentsAppeared);
    $scope.calAverage();
  };

  $scope.addNew = function(personalDetail) {
    $scope.subjectAverages.push({
      'subjectName': "",
    'yearSem': "",
    'studentsAppeared': "",
     'studentsPassed':"",
     'percentage':""

    });
  };
  $scope.parseFloat = function(value) {
    return parseFloat(value);
  };
  $scope.removeRow=function(index){       
       // remove the row specified in index
    $scope.subjectAverages.splice( index, 1);
    $scope.calAverage();
    // if no rows left in the array create a blank array
    if ($scope.subjectAverages.length() === 0){
      $scope.subjectAverages = [];
      $scope.calAverage();
    }

  };

  $scope.calAverage=function()
  {
    var total =0;
    angular.forEach($scope.subjectAverages,function(item){
      total += item.percentage;
    });
    $scope.subjectAverages[0].average = (total/$scope.subjectAverages.length).toFixed(2);

    if($scope.subjectAverages[0].average>=90)
      $scope.subjectAverages[0].point=20;
    else if(($scope.subjectAverages[0].average>=80)&&($scope.subjectAverages[0].average<90))
      $scope.subjectAverages[0].point=15;
    else if(($scope.subjectAverages[0].average>=70)&&($scope.subjectAverages[0].average<80))
      $scope.subjectAverages[0].point=10;
    else if(($scope.subjectAverages[0].average>=60)&&($scope.subjectAverages[0].average<70))
      $scope.subjectAverages[0].point=5;
    else
      $scope.subjectAverages[0].point=0;
}
$scope.isDisabled = false;

  $scope.saveavg=function(){

  $scope.isDisabled = true; 
 $rootScope.progressBarValue=($rootScope.progressBarValue+$scope.subjectAverages[0].point);
 $rootScope.progressBar=(10/8)*$rootScope.progressBarValue;
 getAverage.subAverage($scope.subjectAverages[0].average);
 postSubAverage.postData($scope.subjectAverages);

}  

}]);

app.service("postSubAverage",['$http',function($http){
return{
  postData:function(subAverage){
  $http({
    url: '/appraisalform/subaverage',
    method: "POST",
    data: subAverage,
    headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(postData){ //.success is deprecated,so use .then
    alert("Updated Successfully");
})
  .catch(function(err){//using .catch instead of .error as it is deprecated
    console.log("Error in request =>", err)
})
}
}}])
```

when i click on save button 
router.post is fired

```
    router.post('/subaverage',function(req,res){

  console.log("deepak");
  });
```

but the problem is deepak is written is console immediately but the after some time its again apperring

deepak

POST /appraisalform/subaverage - - ms - -

deepak

i am using angular + javascript in the pug file.
can anyone help with this.
thankyou

Comment: what's the problem, it called twice?

Comment: yes. why is it being called twice and how to have only one call

Comment: could be , that need to push event preventDefault, for not do the native event?

Comment: can u give me an idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Could be tried this :

```
$scope.saveavg=function(event){

  $scope.isDisabled = true; 
 $rootScope.progressBarValue=($rootScope.progressBarValue+$scope.subjectAverages[0].point);
 $rootScope.progressBar=(10/8)*$rootScope.progressBarValue;
 getAverage.subAverage($scope.subjectAverages[0].average);
 postSubAverage.postData($scope.subjectAverages);
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

Because the second called could be by native navigator.
And other idea is using ng-submi t only, and not using click and submit.
Expect it helps.
tks